# why does not the compiler give an error for non existence of try-catch block?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, try-catch

My question is why in the following JSP file when I write print(), the compiler does not give an error for not writing try-catch?

```
<ul>
    <%
      for (String food:foods)
              out.print("<li>"+food+"</li>");
    %>
</ul>
```

print() signature :

```
public abstract void print(String s )throws java.io.IOException
```

Comment: JSPs are compiled to servlets (check out the compiled version of your JSP). Servlet handler functions are declared to throw java.io.IOException.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks. where can I check the compiled version of my JSP?

Comment: Depends on the container and environment; IIRC Tomcat has a `work` directory or something like that.